# CSS: overlay looks fine on Chrome, but not in Firefox 3: how do I fix the vertical offset?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

http://ttt-ai.heroku.com/

If you get to game over screen (its tic tac toe, so it won't take long), in chrome, the overlay fits the board. But in Firefox 3, the overlay is shifted down a few pixels.

How can I change my CSS to be more consistent?

Comment: Comparing in Photoshop screen captures from Firefox/Chrome, they look almost *identical*. Can you provide screenshots showing the difference you're talking about?

Comment: Be sure you aren't confused over the difference in height the top bar area in both browsers takes up. (Also please specify exact version numbers — Firefox is on version 3.6 at this point, and the latest stable Chrome version changes virtually every hour.)

Comment: just tried your game in Chrome 9.0 and Firefox 3.6.13, and besides me losing twice I don't see any issues. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are positioning .overlay_container with lots of trickery (negative margins), you should put it inside .board, which has position absolute, and then add:

```
.overlay_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This ensures that the position matches all browsers, and if the board size changes the overlay will adapt to it.

Here is a demo stripped to the bare minimum
http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/qYejG/